# Can't Position Image over background image (Html, Bootstrap, CSS)

Tags: html, css

Alright so I have an issue with "advanced" positioning of div's, elements(?), whatever over other div's and such. I'm really just not sure how to center objects over others. I've attempted this using multiple methods, reading responses on here and looking up every tutorial ever but I just can't seem to understand. :/

Here is my latest attempt to center and overlay an image on top of another image.

```
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="file:///E:/HTML_CODE/HexStars.png" alt="HexStars" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="file:///E:/HTML_CODE/HexLogo.png" alt="HexStars"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

My initial thought at completing this task was to just use a background-image and not having to hassle with overlaying one on top of the other as I imagined it would just ignore the background-image considering its in the background.

After My attempt failed there I just tried using a fluid container for both img's setting the 'background' image as relative and the latter to absolute with no luck there either.

9 times out of 10 the photo im trying to overlay just sits underneath the photo im trying to have chill in the back.

Sorry for such a long post im just hoping that someone can help explain how to rearrange images as im not sure how people magically know pixel coords and can layout img maps in a snap.

Anyways i haven't slept in awhile im probably incoherent. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Why doesnt this work????

```
  body {
        background-color: #1a1a1a;
        background-image: file:///E:/HTML_CODE/HexStars.png("HexStars");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
```

Im so dumb, I figured out how to use the css background-image but im still confused on the upper half of my question.

Comment: post your whole HTML and CSS files

Answer (score 0):

> After My attempt failed there I just tried using a fluid container for
>   both img's setting the 'background' image as relative and the latter
>   to absolute with no luck there either.

Try this the other way around. `position: absolute` takes the image out of the flow of the DOM making it possible to have other elements on top of it. You want `position:absolute` on the background img container, and `position:relative` on the image on top.

> Why doesnt this work????
>
> body {
>       background-color: #1a1a1a;
>       background-image: file:///E:/HTML_CODE/HexStars.png("HexStars");
>       background-repeat: no-repeat;
>       background-attachment: fixed; }

The background image value doesn't look like it's formatted correctly. It should look more like this:
`background-image: url("paper.gif");` Or given the example you provided something like this: `background-image: url("file:///E:/HTML_CODE/HexStars.png");`

Comment: Ha I realized my mistake on the css right after posting >_<. However I will try those position settings. Thanks a ton for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

HTML:

```
<div class="image img img-responsive img-thumbnail full-width">
    <img src="......" alt />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.image img{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This will center your image vertically. If you want it horizontally centered add translateX(-50%) and left: 50%;

Comment: ah! Overflow, thats what i was looking for! I will for sure try the rest. Thanks for your help :)